# Unable to run Python flask app in different port using docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

I am running Flask application in Python using docker-compose. I am able to run the Flask app using 5000 port. I am trying to run it on 6000 besides another Flask app running on 5000. But I am unable run it on 6000 port. Any help would be appreciated.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - "6000:5000"
```

app.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==1.1.1
```

Port 6000 is listening. I am able to get a connection succeeded by executing nc command with host and port.

I am unable to run the app on port 6000.

I got the following when I hit http://#{HOST_IP}:6000 in browser

```
This site can’t be reached
The web page at http://#{HOST_IP}:6000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
```

Comment: what do the docker logs say ? does the server start ?

Comment: Yes. server gets started. Docker logs says "Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/"

Comment: what do you mean by `I am trying to run it on 6000 besides another Flask app running on 5000`? Do you run the same application in a different container, the same container? Please share the sequence of commands that can be rerun to reproduce the issue you face

Comment: according to your **docker logs** @Galet your flask application is running on `http://#{HOST_IP}:5000/`

Comment: do you have a healthz route on the app? can you post the results from that

Comment: @rok Yes. I am running the same flask app on 5000 and 6000 in different containers.

Comment: @M_x I have already running the same app in different container on 5000 port. I want my second app in diffferent container to run on 6000 port.

Comment: @Cptmaxon I don't have health route of the app

Comment: @rok All the docker and other files are listed above. I just run docker-compose up to start the container.

Comment: @Galet I've setup exactly what you have done, I couldn't able to up the container. as its failing with an error. `NameError: name 'app' is not defined`. Can you please update me whether you've imported flask or not in app.py?

Comment: can you share the full source code of the python application, please? what's `app`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`6000` is unsafe port that is why browser not allowing to access the application.

[how-to-fix-err-unsafe-port-error-on-chrome-when-browsing-to-unsafe-ports](https://superuser.com/questions/188006/how-to-fix-err-unsafe-port-error-on-chrome-when-browsing-to-unsafe-ports)

But you should not allow this port, just try to publish another port.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - "5001:5000"
```

For downvoter

[image]

Here is [Github Repo](https://github.com/Adiii717/dockerize-flask-app) to verify this

```
git clone https://github.com/Adiii717/dockerize-flask-app.git
cd dockerize-flask-app/
# this will not work in the browser
PORT=6000 docker-compose up
```

Comment: Any reason for down vote? The port is off course unsafe

Comment: It's working after changing the port from 6000 to 7000.

Comment: @Adiii while the port may be unsafe, the error experienced by the user was `The web page at  ... might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.` anyway, i upvoted if it helps the user, even though app code he shared is not full and the issue can't be fully reproduced

Comment: @rok thanks, yes the error is expected in that case too, I already attached screenshot for the complete error message.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined any routes. The app server has no idea what routes are available nor does it know what you want to return, so you need to specify that.

Here's a more complete version of `app.py`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Please refer to the [Flask tutorial for a minimal app](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application).